# Sharing an Xcode project between different teams

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox, collaboration

I'm a novice iOS developer with a basic knowledge of Xcode. I have one app in the app store that I made myself with Titanium. For a next project I've enlisted the help of two more experienced programmers in another city. I have a question in two parts about the collaboration between us:

1. I want to propose a work routine that gives me access to the project as they are working on it, so that I can device test builds during the development process - without interfering with the coding. What is the best way to do this? Is sharing the project or codebase via Dropbox an option? Does anybody have any experience with this?
2. Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of when pursuing this kind of work routine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use source control. Github is a great place to start. (private repositories will cost money though.)

I used to use DropBox to share code between my two machines, but DropBox would routinely ruin work if I wasnt careful. **DropBox is NOT version control.** If you do insist in using Dropbox, don't open your code on more than one machine at once. Nuff said.

Answer (score 3):

Use a source control system like Subversion, Git, Mercurial.

XCode has built in support for Subversion/Git.